# Criar botão menu na parte inferior em Google maps v2 android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Como criar o botão Menu igual o App do Maps. Segue abaixo um exemplo no quadrado vermelho.

Alguém poderia passar um exemplo ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Creio que seja um [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html):

Ele permite um fragment ficar "escondido" à esquerda ou à direita da tela.

Comment: Então até aí blz, eu falo de como criar esse interface ou seja esse modelo de botão, com Toolbar eu consigo, mais eu queria do jeito da imagem.

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar os trechos de códigos principais a sua resposta, pois a URL pode sair do ar...

Comment: João Paulo Pulga, acho que você não entendeu a pergunta, estou procurando trechos de código e/ou exemplos de como faço aquele botão...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o RelativeLayout na tela toda, colocar um ImageView com a imagem que você quer que seja seu "botão" e usar os atributos 
            `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Depois um `layout_marginBottom="5dp" para não ficar colado na parte debaixo.

Segue exemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_drawer"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Mais é pra deixar com aquela fundo branco, com a sombra e a borda ?

Comment: Você pode usar a imagem que quiser. Caso queira usar sombra que não esteja na imagem use um shape